# Pertaining to Newton's laws, how do so many objects acheive perfect equilibrium?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, equilibrium

Suppose a light is hanging from a ceiling. Supposedly, the force of tension pulling it up is exactly the same as the force of gravity pulling it down. Why is it that the tension happens to be exactly the same as the weight?

Comment: What would happen if the tension were greater than the weight?

Comment: It's the nature of tension to adjust itself to be equal to the weight.  It's inherently a response force.

Answer (score 1):

The simple word is "damping".

Initially when you hang an object from a string (spring, etc), it will move - side to side, and up and down. While it is moving, there will be a changing force on the object - after all it is accelerating / decelerating. This shows up as a force in the string that changes with time.

In all "real" systems, there is also a component of friction (drag). This component resists the motion of the object, and allows the energy associated with the motion to dissipate. Mathematically, this process never stops - the amplitude might decay with some exponential term, but that doesn't ever make it equal to zero. Practically, the motion stops after "a while" and the object appears to be hanging still.

When it is stationary, the sum of all forces on the object must equal zero. If there is just "gravity" and "string tension", it follows that these two are exactly equal. If they are not, then the object is not stationary...

Comment: So it's a response force just like normal force and gravity?

Comment: When the object is stationary, the analogy is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

When the light hangs off the ceiling by means of the electrical cable, the cable actually acts as a very stiff spring. The light bulb provides a downward force due to its weight $mg$. The cable acts like a spring, slightly idealised here as a Hookean spring which provides the counter force (what you called the force of tension) of $k\Delta y$ with $k$ the elastic modulus of the cable and $\Delta y$ the small amount that the cable stretches under the weight $mg$. So the balance of forces is:

$mg=k\Delta y$.

In reality $\Delta y$ is almost imperceptible because $m$ is small and $k$ is large.

Something similar happens when the cable is attached to the ceiling: at that point too some very small stretching in the ceiling fitting causes it to provide the counter force that prevents light bulb plus cable to fall.